# Master page image not displaying in content page?

Tags: asp.net, css, visual-studio, html, master-pages

I have a master page with one `div` Header.

```
#header
        {
             background-image: url("images/ST_ERP_2.jpg");
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-position: right top;

            height: 200px;
            width: 1200px;
        }
```

below is the header `div`

```
<div id="header" >
            <h1>
                Header goes here</h1>               
</div>
```

Both the above code snippents are in my master page.

Now I have a content page (`xyz.aspx`) which is inside some directory.

The image (ST_ERP_2.jpg) is in the `images` folder.

Now when I try to view the page (`xyz.aspx`) in a browser it doesn't show me the image which I have set for `background-image` instead it shows me a blank white area.
What could be the problem?

**NOTE:**

1. I have also tried `background-image: url("~/images/ST_ERP_2.jpg");` but it 
   doesn't help me.
2. I am using VS2010 and ASP.NET

**MASTER PAGE:**

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Site.master.cs" Inherits="Site" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="ajax" %>
<%--<%@ Register Assembly="AccordionSiteMap" Namespace="FranchiseBlast.UserControls.Interface"
    TagPrefix="lb" %>--%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">

    <style type="text/css">

        #wrapper
        {
            background: #FFFFFF;
            margin: 0px auto;
            width: 1200px;
            height: 1024px;
        }

        #header
        {
             background-image: url("images/ST_ERP_2.jpg");
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-position: right top;

            height: 200px;
            width: 1200px;
        }

        #footer
        {
            background: #838283;
            height: 40px;
            width: 1200px;
            margin: 600px 0px;
        }
    </style>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body style="background: LightBlue">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="header" >
            <h1>
                Header goes here</h1>
            <br />

        </div>
        <!--Header-->


 .... content place holder and etc  ......


         <div id="footer" style="clear: both">
            <h3>
                Footer goes here</h3>
        </div>
        <!--Footer-->
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is the background-image line in the Master Page or in a .css file? In other words do you have a <style> tag or a <link> tag in your Master page?

Comment: i have a <style> tag in my master page

Comment: @MartinBrown  see master page code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try replacing the background-image with this:

```
background-image: url(<%=ResolveClientUrl("~/images/ST_ERP_2.jpg")%>);
```

Comment: Thank you so so so so much ...Martin........it works fine...problem solved!! hurrey!!!

Comment: You could also use ResolveUrl(string) the difference between that and ResolveClientUrl(string) is explained in http://www.andornot.com/blog/post/ResolveUrl-vs-ResolveClientUrl.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
background-image: url("../images/ST_ERP_2.jpg");
```

Comment: i have three level of directory now i have changed as per your instruction it works fine for the page with first level directory but same problem for page inside directory of level two and three. thank you so much for answering

Comment: For 2nd lavel of  directory ../../ smiler for 3rd level ../../../

Comment: i have define background-image in master page. see my master page code..how could i change( which you have suggested)  for page at different level of directory?

Comment: Still you are not changing your url.If image define in master page then there is not any problem to see that image when your page is loaded in that master page.No matter that page is inside directory level of 2 or 3.I think there is another problem.

Comment: i have tried change you have suggested but it doesn't works for the page other than page in first level directory...thank you so much for answering